# How to solve fatal error c1083 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I am following this walkthrough to compile my C program in Visual Studio 2019:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019

My program contains the lines "#include R.h" and "#include math.h". 
Unfortunately, Visual Studio yields the following error: 
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'R.h': No such file or directory

I found many solutions to this problem on the internet, but none of them appears to work.
Could you help me out?

Comment: Where is located the `R.h` file, how do you configured VS (compilation option, include directory?)

Comment: It seem like compiler can not find the mentioned header files. If the headers are not belong to windows sdk then add the header file location to additional includes section of the project properties page.

Comment: I actually can not find the R.h file on my computer. And I only carried out the steps in the walkthrough. Where can I find the additional includes section? Thanks for helping me!!

Comment: Welcome! Please invest the time, take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back end [edit] your question, providing a [example]. -- Most probaly you need to install "R".